# Create a wire roll fall animation

Tags: animation

I want to create a animation of a rolled wire falling form a 3 meter distance and be able to see how the wire falls and becomes tangled.

Sorry for my bad english

It would be a wire like in the next image
[image: wire]

I would appreciate a lot your help since I didn't find any information

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck

Comment: and a sample animation or a link to yt how it should look like would help as well. Animations can have a lot of variations and it is not clear how yours should look lke.

Comment: Are we to understand you want the wire to unroll, as it falls, or hold together, reasonably well?

Comment: 1. If it's possible I want it to unroll but the important thing is once it bounces it will get tangled. 2. I couldn't find a video but what I'm trying to simulate is a bad packaging from a bongard, when they use the auto accumulate the rolled wire falls and gets tangled but if it's not enabled the wire rolls from the base of the container (https://youtu.be/rOwPAookusA) 3. I tried to generate a spiral and increase its depth but I can't use the rigid body to make it fall. To be honest I just started with Blender.